# Setting up NGINX / Linux development environment with Vagrant and Chef (Solo)

Tags: linux, nginx, webserver, vagrant, chef-solo

### As a disclaimer I am rather new to Linux after recently moving the Microsoft .NET IIS stack

The problem: I am having difficulty provisioning a ready made environment to develop against using the following...

- Vagrant
- Chef
- VirtualBox
- Apt (cookbook)
- Apache2 (cookbook)

The error I am receiving is (when hitting the hostname or IP of the virtual machine)

**ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED**

There is a lot of code so, I will just post my vagrant file and role...

```
Vagrantfile
-----------------    

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

    config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 4567
    config.vm.host_name = "www.example.vm"


    config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
        chef.cookbooks_path = "cookbooks"
      end
end



vagrant-test-boc.rb
-----------------  

# Name of the role should match the name of the file
name "vagrant-test-box"

# Run list function we mentioned earlier
run_list(
    "recipe[apt]",
    "recipe[apache2]"
)
```

Any suggestions, guidelines examples would be most welcome!

Thanks!

**Additional Edit: I have been advised to look into setting up an NGINX server using similar techniques, would this be another question or would it be valid along this thread?**

My main resources have been....

https://adamcod.es/2013/01/15/vagrant-is-easy-chef-is-hard-part2.html
https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/chef_solo.html

Comment: you use chrome ? try another browser, chrome manage dns a bit differently

Comment: Thanks Frédéric, but I have tried in Safari and get the same response....

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to access the server `www.example.vm` (on port `4567`) from your host ?

If that's the case, then the issue is probably that you've not told your host that `www.example.vm` is really an alias to your own host (localhost). Otherwise your host has no way of knowing that it shouldn't do a dns lookup and attempt to send a request to this host over the internet.

On a Unix / OSX box, you can edit your `/etc/hosts`, where you can add your fake domain name to the localhost line, like so: 

`127.0.0.1   localhost www.example.vm`

Hope this helps!  ; )

Comment: From what I can gather it appears that the issue is related to this. After searching through the provisioned box there appears to be no sites (default or otherwise). This one would suggest that I need to set one up as part of the provisioning process. I have also ben advised to move from Apache2 to NGINX, which itself is now proving difficult (and may need another question)